# Regularity of solution to Cauchy problem given regular initial data

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, regularity, cauchy-problem

Let $f\in L^2_1([0,T]\times \mathbb{T}^m)$ (Sobolev space of maps of regularity $1$, $\mathbb{T}^m$ is the $m$-dimensional torus)
be a solution of a Cauchy problem
$$\frac{d}{dt} f(t) = A f(t)$$
$$f(0) = g\in L_{k-\frac 1 2}^2(\mathbb{T}^m) $$
where $A:L^2_j(\mathbb{T}^m)\to L_{j-1}^2(\mathbb{T}^m)$ is a first order differential operator.

> Q. Does it follows that $f\in L^2_k([0,T]\times \mathbb{T}^m)$ at least for $k=2$?  Does it hold an inequality like $$\|f(t)\|_{L_{k-\frac 1 2}^2}\leq e^{\omega t}\|g\|_{L_{k-\frac 1 2}^2}\:?$$

I think the latter estimate should hold if the Cauchy problem is well posed and hence admits a propagator (correct me if I'm wrong please, I'm not an expert in PDEs). But maybe we do not have a propagator then I wonder if given a solution and an enough regular initial datum we can still control the regularity of the solution over the product

Comment: What do you mean by $L^2_1((0,T)\times\Omega)$ and $L^2_k(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: Anyway, a PDE in a bounded domain needs to specify boundary conditions, and yours certainly does. What are they ?

Comment: $L^2_k(X)$ is a  Sobolev spaces of regularity $k$ and  $p=2$

Comment: You mean conditions on $\partial \Omega$? I abstracted my  study case  where I had a torus instead of $\Omega$ so being closed I had no condition, does that affect so much the solution?

Comment: Is $f$ scalar? If not, and $f$ is vector-valued, can you say more about the structure of the coefficients of $A$?

Comment: If your data is only in $L^2_{k-1/2}$, I find it highly unlikely that your solution can be guaranteed to be in $L^2_k$. (You have simple examples when $m = 1$ and $A$ has constant coefficient [linear advection] where the method of characteristic solutions shows that you don't gain the extra regularity.)

Comment: @WillieWong Let's assume for simplicity that $f$ is scalar (if it doesn't work in this case, the vectorial case is even more unlikely). 
Let's say that $k=2$, then that seems more reasonable, also notice that I am assuminig that the solution is already in $L^2_1$ so I want to improve regularity only of $1$ derivative in the $t$-direction and $1/2$ derivative on the slices.

If $k>2$, maybe I should assume that $f\in L^2_{k-1}$ on the cylinder.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain: still, if you have a function of the form $f(t,x) = g(t-x)$, and $g\in L^2_{k - 1/2}$, you cannot have $f\in L^2_k$ (but you will have $f\in L^2_{k-1}$).

Comment: @WillieWong thank you for your observations. Is there a known formula (any reference would help) for Cauchy problems that asserts something like that? I.e. if the initial condition is in $L^2_r(\mathbb{T}^m)$ then a solution will be at least in $L^2_{r-\frac 1 2}([0,T]\times \mathbb{T}^m)$?
Also, has the regularity to be constant? I.e. is possible that $f|_{[0,T/2]\times \mathbb{T}^m)}\in L^2_{k-1}$ and $f|_{(T/2,T]\times \mathbb{T}^m)}\in L^2_{k}$?